Display problem in my form with a MUI Autocomplete
I am new using Material UI and Tailwind CSS, what happens is that in my form, when I have multiple data in my Autocomplete, the input of the Autocomplete overlaps and stays over the next DatePicker. Why is this happening? I leave an image where shows my problem:

also, I'm gonna leave a part of my LfMultiSelectInput.tsx code
return (
    <div className="relative mb-2 h-auto min-w-full md:min-w-[220px]">
      <label className="mb-2 block text-base font-medium text-white-500">
        {label}
        {obligatory && (
          <span className="ml-1 text-lg font-semibold text-blue-500">*</span>
        )}
      </label>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            className="autocomplete"
            sx={{
              borderRadius: "50px",
              textAlign: "center",
              display: "flex",
            }}
            multiple
            options={options}
            onChange={(_, newValue) => field.onChange(newValue)}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                inputRef={ref}
                variant="outlined"
                {...field}
                className="block h-12 w-full rounded-full px-3 py-[0.54em] text-base font-medium text-white-500"
              />
            )}
            renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
              value.map((option, index) => (
                <Box
                  sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "no-wrap",
                    gap: 0.5,
                    position: "relative",
                  }}
                >
                  <Chip
                    label={option.label}
                    {...getTagProps({ index })}
                    onDelete={() => {
                      const newValue = [...value]
                      newValue.splice(index, 1)
                      field.onChange(newValue)
                    }}
                    key={option.value}
                    sx={{
                      border: "1px solid white",
                      color: "white",
                      "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
                        color: "white",
                        "&:hover": {
                          color: "#02afef",
                        },
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                </Box>
              ))
            }
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  )

and I would also like to share my form, which is in another component, because the problem may be the divs in which the components are enclosed:
return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <div className="m-4 max-h-min max-w-md rounded-2xl border-2 border-white-500 bg-black-500 p-8">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
            <Stack spacing={2} className="flex flex-col">
              <div className="mt-4">
                <LfInput
                  label="Nombre del proyecto"
                  name="project_name"
                  register={register}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfSelectInput
                  label="Tipo de proyecto"
                  name="project_type_uid"
                  register={register}
                  options={options}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfMultiSelectInput
                  label="Participantes"
                  name="user_uid"
                  control={control}
                  options={freelancers}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfDatePicker
                  label="Fecha de inicio"
                  name="project_start_date"
                  control={control}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <LfDatePicker
                  label="Fecha de entrega"
                  name="project_deadline"
                  control={control}
                  obligatory
                />
              </div>
            </Stack>
            <div className="mt-4 flex content-center justify-center">
              <LfButton>Crear Proyecto</LfButton>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )

Thanks to everyone who can help me!

This could happen if the autocomplete input or one if its containers has a hard-coded height set. If it does, then when content overflows it won't push the content below it down. To fix this you could replace the hard-coded height from height: 40px to min-height: 40px to set a minimum height and allow it to grow beyond that. You should use dev tools to inspect the rendered out markup and see if you can find any elements with a height value set

@zgood Thank u!! The problem was the height of the TextField. You are the best!!
